# to remove duplicates and making separate column for entries whose date are not continuous

Tags: r

I have a data set as given in example data set employee:

```
s.no e.name s.date    e.date    s.time e.time total.hrs

1    George  1-Jan-19  10-Jan-19 10:45   11:45  1
2    George  10-Jan-19 15-Jan-19 06:00   09:00  3
3    George  15-Jan-19 15-Jan-19 12:00   03:00  3
4    George  5-Feb-19  18-Feb-19 12:50   14:50  2
5    Jacob   2-Feb-19  20-Feb-19 15:50   16:50  1
6    Jacob   20-Feb-19 24-Feb-19 14:30   18:30  4
7    Jacob   3-Dec-19  25-Dec-19 06:40   11:40  5
8    Jacob   25-Dec-19 30-Dec-19 09:40   12:40  3
9    Mike    02-Jun-19 02-Jun-19 6:40    07:40  1
10   Mike    02-Jun-19 02-Jun-19 2:45    3:45   1
11   Mike    02-Jun-19 20-Jun-19 10:00   12:00  2
12   Mike    23-Jun-19  25-Jun-19 4:00   5:00   1
```

My desired output is:

```
s.no e.name s.date    e.date    s.time e.time total.hrs

1    George  1-Jan-19  15-Jan-19 10:45   03:00  7
2    George  5-Feb-19  18-Feb-19 12:50   14:50  2
3    Jacob   2-Feb-19  24-Feb-19 15:50   18:30  5
4    Jacob   3-Dec-19  30-Dec-19 06:40   12:40  8
5    Mike    2-Jun-19  20-Jun-19  6:40    12:00 4
6    Mike    23-Jun-19  25-Jun-19 4:00   5:00   1
```

I was using dplyr library to summarize this but i was having some problem with that i was using this code but i'm not getting my desired output

```
employee <- employee %>% group_by(e.name) %>% summarise(
        s.date=first(s.date),
        e.date=last(e.date), 
        s.time=first(s.time),
        e.time=last(e.time),
        total.hrs=sum(total.hrs))
```

From my code i'm getting result as follows

```
s.no e.name s.date    e.date    s.time e.time total.hrs

1    George  1-Jan-19  18-Jan-19 10:45   14:50  6
2    Jacob   2-Feb-19  30-Dec-19 15:50   12:40  12
```

but i want my result like this

```
s.no e.name s.date    e.date    s.time e.time total.hrs

1    George  1-Jan-19  15-Jan-19 10:45   03:00  7
2    George  5-Feb-19  18-Feb-19 12:50   14:50  2
3    Jacob   2-Feb-19  24-Feb-19 15:50   18:30  5
4    Jacob   3-Dec-19  30-Dec-19 06:40   12:40  8
5    Mike    2-Jun-19  20-Jun-19  6:40    12:00 4
6    Mike    23-Jun-19  25-Jun-19 4:00   5:00   1
```

Comment: do you need the s.time and e.time as well ? because they don't appear to overlap

Comment: i just want them as my first and last entry s.time as first and e.time as last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data.table...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

res = DT[, .(
  s.no = first(s.no),
  s.date = first(s.date), 
  e.date = last(e.date), 
  s.time = first(s.time), 
  e.time = last(e.time),
  total.hrs = sum(total.hrs)
), by=.(e.name, .g = cumsum(s.date != shift(e.date, fill=first(s.date))))]

res[, .g := NULL]

   e.name s.no    s.date    e.date s.time e.time total.hrs
1: George    1  1-Jan-19 15-Jan-19  10:45  03:00         7
2: George    4  5-Feb-19 18-Feb-19  12:50  14:50         2
3:  Jacob    5  2-Feb-19 24-Feb-19  15:50  18:30         5
4:  Jacob    7  3-Dec-19 30-Dec-19  06:40  12:40         8
5:   Mike    9 02-Jun-19 20-Jun-19   6:40  12:00         4
6:   Mike   12 23-Jun-19 25-Jun-19   4:00   5:00         1
```

Analogue in dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% group_by(e.name, .g = cumsum(s.date != lag(e.date, default=first(s.date)))) %>% 
summarise(
  s.no = first(s.no),
  s.date = first(s.date), 
  e.date = last(e.date), 
  s.time = first(s.time), 
  e.time = last(e.time),
  total.hrs = sum(total.hrs)
) %>% select(-.g)

# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   e.name [3]
  e.name  s.no s.date    e.date    s.time e.time total.hrs
  <chr>  <int> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>  <chr>      <int>
1 George     1 1-Jan-19  15-Jan-19 10:45  03:00          7
2 George     4 5-Feb-19  18-Feb-19 12:50  14:50          2
3 Jacob      5 2-Feb-19  24-Feb-19 15:50  18:30          5
4 Jacob      7 3-Dec-19  30-Dec-19 06:40  12:40          8
5 Mike       9 02-Jun-19 20-Jun-19 6:40   12:00          4
6 Mike      12 23-Jun-19 25-Jun-19 4:00   5:00           1
```

This answer...

- skips reading in the data
- skips conversion of dates and times to proper formats
- assumes the data is sorted

@Mouad's answer is more thorough in that it fixes these (as the OP should do with their real data). The approach there is also essentially the same -- group by both `e.name` and the `cumsum` of flags for where `s.date` changes from its previous/shifted/lagged value.

Data

```
library(data.table)
DT = fread("s.no e.name s.date    e.date    s.time e.time total.hrs
1    George  1-Jan-19  10-Jan-19 10:45   11:45  1
2    George  10-Jan-19 15-Jan-19 06:00   09:00  3
3    George  15-Jan-19 15-Jan-19 12:00   03:00  3
4    George  5-Feb-19  18-Feb-19 12:50   14:50  2
5    Jacob   2-Feb-19  20-Feb-19 15:50   16:50  1
6    Jacob   20-Feb-19 24-Feb-19 14:30   18:30  4
7    Jacob   3-Dec-19  25-Dec-19 06:40   11:40  5
8    Jacob   25-Dec-19 30-Dec-19 09:40   12:40  3
9    Mike    02-Jun-19 02-Jun-19 6:40    07:40  1
10   Mike    02-Jun-19 02-Jun-19 2:45    3:45   1
11   Mike    02-Jun-19 20-Jun-19 10:00   12:00  2
12   Mike    23-Jun-19  25-Jun-19 4:00   5:00   1")
```

Comment: s.date != lag(e.date, default=first(s.date) i m getting error here in ops factor levels set for factor are different i m using dplyr

Comment: @xyz This is a common problem in R. When you read your data in, it interpreted s.date and e.date as factors (categorical variables with distinct possible values) so they cannot be compared like `!=`. You can maybe address it by using stringsAsFactors=FALSE as in Mouad's answer when reading in the data. Alternately, convert with as.character. For that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35774173

Comment: i m still not getting my desired output it is still making other entries for dates which are continuous i want days which are continuous in one entry   and if sequence of date breaks then  it should be in separate

Comment: @xyz Sorry, I don't think I can help you to debug this way. Maybe you want to edit your question to include a reproducible example (guidance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250) or, probably better, post the reproducible example as part of a new question if it is substantially different (and would make the two answers already posted no longer valid).

Comment: can you please check again i have edited my question

Comment: @xyz Okay, I have edited the question. The code still seems to work for this case..?

Answer (score 2):

```
    require(dplyr)

    my_df <- read.table(text = 
    's.no e.name s.date    e.date    s.time e.time total.hrs
    1    George  1-Jan-19  10-Jan-19 10:45   11:45  1
    2    George  10-Jan-19 15-Jan-19 06:00   09:00  3
    3    George  5-Feb-19  18-Feb-19 12:50   14:50  2
    4    Jacob   2-Feb-19  20-Feb-19 15:50   16:50  1
    5    Jacob   20-Feb-19 24-Feb-19 14:30   18:30  4
    5    Jacob   3-Dec-19  25-Dec-19 06:40   11:40  5
    6    Jacob   25-Dec-19 30-Dec-19 09:40   12:40  3', 
    header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  %>% as_tibble()

    my_df <- 
         my_df %>% 
          mutate(s.date2 = as.Date(s.date, '%d-%B-%y'),
                 e.date2 = as.Date(e.date, '%d-%B-%y')) %>% 
          arrange(e.name, s.date2) %>% 
          group_by(e.name) %>%  
          mutate(lag_e.date2 = lag(e.date2,1)) %>%  
          ungroup %>%  
          mutate(new_episode = as.numeric(is.na(lag_e.date2) | s.date2 != lag_e.date2 )) %>%  
          mutate(episode = cumsum(new_episode)) %>% 
          group_by(episode) %>%  
          mutate(asc_rank = rank(s.date2), 
                 desc_rank = rank(desc(s.date2)), 
                 sum_hours = sum(total.hrs)) %>%  
          ungroup
```

then

```
 my_df %>%  
          mutate(s.date_new = if_else(asc_rank ==1, s.date2, as.Date('1900-01-01')),
                 s.time_new = if_else(asc_rank ==1, s.time, '00:00'),
                 e.date_new = if_else(desc_rank ==1, e.date2, as.Date('1900-01-01')),
                 e.time_new = if_else(desc_rank ==1, e.time, '00:00')) %>%  
          select(e.name, s.date_new, e.date_new, s.time_new, e.time_new, sum_hours, episode) %>% 
          group_by(episode) %>%  
          mutate(s.date = max(s.date_new, na.rm = TRUE), 
                 e.date = max(e.date_new, na.rm = TRUE),
                 s.time = max(s.time_new, na.rm = TRUE),
                 e.time = max(e.time_new, na.rm = TRUE), 
                 sum_hours = max(sum_hours)) %>%  
          ungroup %>% 
          select(e.name, s.date, e.date, s.time, e.time, sum_hours) %>%  distinct 


        # # A tibble: 4 x 6
        # e.name s.date     e.date     s.time e.time sum_hours
        # <chr>  <date>     <date>     <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>
        # 1 George 2019-01-01 2019-01-15 10:45  09:00          4
        # 2 George 2019-02-05 2019-02-18 12:50  14:50          2
        # 3 Jacob  2019-02-02 2019-02-24 15:50  18:30          5
        # 4 Jacob  2019-12-03 2019-12-30 06:40  12:40          8
        # > 
        #
```

Comment: Error in strptime(x, format, tz = "GMT") : 
  object 's.Date_new' not found having this error while running your code

Comment: I'm not getting the error, plus there is not variable with the name `s.Date_new`, it might have been a typo, R is case sensitive.